# @jbossuat.abcnet.in:9002: java.net.BindException: Address already in use java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: linux, esb, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I have already deployed some jar in JBoss Fuse server which is exposing two rest endpoint on port 9001 and 9002. Now i have made some changes in source code and want to deploy a new jar. Since i am doing hot deployment i am just calling ./karaf stop and placing new jar in fuseinstallDir/deploy . But when i start Karaf server using fuseinstallDir/start then i am getting java.net.BindException: Address already in use. I have tried to check which process is using this port but didnt get any process after stopping karaf server

Answer (score 1):

You should hot-deploy while the server is running, not while its stopped. Because it will startup the old application first as it was not uninstalled first.

Also its not recommended to deploy via copying files to the deploy folder. Install install via the commands from the shell.